# How to create a Trapezoid transformation in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, transformation

Is it possible to transform a usercontrol in Silverlight to a shape of a Trapezoid?

Like this:

```
     _________
    /         \
   /___________\
```

I will do this to a usercontrol, and not to an image.

Comment: You could do it by using a 3D transformation, though the top would be further away than the base so might look odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing the content of the usercontrol inside a border, it is possible to achive the transformation by adding this to the XAML:

```
<Border.Projection>
       <PlaneProjection RotationX="-45" ></PlaneProjection>   
</Border.Projection>
```